# Why STL containers can insert using const iterator

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, constants

Why STL containers can insert using `const_iterator`? For example, there is

```
iterator std::list::insert (const_iterator position, const value_type& val);
```

I have thought that `const_iterator`'s does not allow to modify container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an element is inserted into a list, the **other elements are not modified**. The iterator is only used to determine the insertion position, not to modify (= *call non-const member function on*) any of the existing elements.

Even `erase` can take a `const_iterator`. Again, this is because **erasing an element does not modify it**, either. This may sound strange, but it's trivial if you consider this:

```
void f()
{
    std::string const s = "foo";
    // the function ends and s is destroyed even though it was constant
}
```

Comment: I like this example. I balked at first but it's actually a spot on analogy. On second glance, Alf's example is pretty much the same, if not quite as well stated.

Answer (score 3):

They are called `const_iterator`s because they don't allow you to change underlying value, not the container itself. You still need to have a non-const list to insert elements to, because `insert` is a non-const member of `std::list`, but the interface is made in the least restricting way.

Consider that you have a function that lets you find and `iterator` to some element. It doesn't need to change anything, so you design it to return `const_iterator`. And then you want to insert to `list` at this iterator, but you wouldn't be able to, if the interface for the `list` was more restricted then it is.

Answer (score 2):

> *"I have thought that const_iterator's does not allow to modify container."*

You should note that

```
iterator std::list::insert (const_iterator position, const value_type& val);
         // ^^^^^^
```

actually is a non const member function of [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert).
You still need a mutable `std::list` instance to apply it, the container isn't modified via the iterator. The `position` parameter, just designates where to insert a new value.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Spo1ler's answer, note that C++11 changed a bunch of library functions to do precisely this:

> `[C++11: C.2.12]:` **Clause 23: containers library**
>
> **23.2.3, 23.2.4**
>
> **Change:** Signature changes: from `iterator` to `const_iterator` parameters
>   **Rationale:** Overspecification.
>   **Effects:** The signatures of the following member functions changed from taking an `iterator` to taking a `const_iterator`:
>
> - `insert(iter, val)` for `vector`, `deque`, `list`, `set`, `multiset`, `map`, `multimap`
> - `insert(pos, beg, end)` for `vector`, `deque`, `list`, `forward_list`
> - `erase(iter)` for `set`, `multiset`, `map`, `multimap`
> - `erase(begin, end)` for `set`, `multiset`, `map`, `multimap`
> - all forms of `list::splice`
> - all forms of `list::merge`
>
> Valid C++ 2003 code that uses these functions may fail to compile with this International Standard.

For example:

[image]

They did this because they'd originally assumed the way you do, but later realised that it made little sense and caused people headaches for no reason. It was "overspecified".

A `const_iterator` is helpful for guaranteeing *element* immutability whilst iterating over a range, but it would be needlessly restrictive if it also meant you couldn't use it to describe a location in a container at which to perform a mutation. You can always have the container itself be `const` in that scope if you need both behaviours.

However it should be noted that [this change isn't universally liked, because](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/lwg/issue2059):

> `map::erase` (and several related methods) took an iterator in C++03, but take a `const_iterator` in C++0x. This breaks code where the map's `key_type` has a constructor which accepts an iterator (for example a template constructor), as the compiler cannot choose between `erase(const key_type&)` and `erase(const_iterator)`.